# excel truncating phone number

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a csv file that contains cells such as "+1.8882789780".
When viewed in Excel, it loses the last digit possibly due to excel truncation.

Is there a way to either change the setting in Excel to prevent this from happening or change the csv file in some way?

One way is to wrap single quotes around the cell contents in addition to the double quotes.

```
"'+1.8882789780'"
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/a/427422/76571

Answer (score 1):

Precede the quoted string with an `=` sign, e.g., `="+1.8882789780"`.

Comment: Note that if you're using Excel 2007, it has a bug that might require a workaround (depending on the quoted text). Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates) for details.

Comment: is there a way without changing the actual content? like modifying excel settings?

Comment: Yes.  You can also select the cells of interest, right-click and select `Format Cells ...`, then select `Text`. But you'll need to do that before entering the value.  Once it's been interpreted as a numeric value, the extra digits will have been lost.

Comment: Addition to the comment just above: remember that Excel can't save formatting information in csv file

Comment: @Serge, true, but cells formatted as Text will be saved exactly as entered and displayed.